# How to pull all domains from URL links?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull all the domains from the links using urlparse. But for some reason, sometimes I get a list of domains, and sometimes the following error message:

**NoneType object is not subscriptable**

What's the problem? And how can i fix it? Thank you!

**UPD**: Ok, i already solve it. Here's the solution

```
if arg.name:
try:
    page = requests.get(arg.name)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,features='html.parser')
    links = soup.findAll("a")
    for i in links:

        domain = urlparse(i.get("href")).hostname 
        **if type(domain) == str:**
            if clink.get(domain):
                clink[domain]+=1
            else:
                clink[domain]=1
    for key in sorted(clink, key=lambda x: x[-1]):
        print(key, clink[key])

except Exception as e:
    print("Incorrect address! Try again!" + '\n\n' + "More about this error: " + '\n\n' + str(e))
```

Comment: Show us a list of the links and the full error traceback!

Comment: Thanks guys! I already found the solution!